# bash for loop not giving expect results

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am trying to install a WordPress caching plugin on all sites that do not currently contain a caching plugin.  I am looping through all cPanel users but getting some odd results while running it.  One liner is:

```
for i in $(ls -I . -I .. /var/cpanel/users)  ; do 
    WPPATH=$(find /home/$i/public_html/ -type f -name wp-config.php) 
    WPPLUGINPATH="$(echo "${WPPATH//wp-config.php/wp-content/plugins/}")"
    cd $WPPLUGINPATH 
    [ -d $WPPLUGINPATH*cache* ] || \
    wp --allow-root plugin install cache-enabler --skip-plugins --skip-themes
    sleep 3
    chown -R $i: $WPPLUGINPATH
    echo $WPPLUGINPATH
done
```

It is working for most but getting random hits like:

```
/home/userC/public_html/wp-content/plugins/
Error: This does not seem to be a WordPress install.
Pass --path=`path/to/wordpress` or run `wp core download`.
chown: missing operand after ‘userA:’
Try 'chown --help' for more information.
```

You can see something is off as its referencing the path for userC yet chown is erroring about userA

It also states there is no WP install but if I manually cd to that directory, I can run the wp-cli command and install the plugin without issue.

Another error:

```
/home/userA/public_html/wp-content/plugins/
-bash: [: /home/userB/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/: binary operator expected
Warning: cache-enabler: Plugin already installed.
Success: Plugin already installed.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should not use `for (ls...` see [**Bash PItfalls**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: Also relevant: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and [Don't Read Lines With `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: Also, using `set -x` to watch what your scripts are doing in practice will, generally, help you ask better questions about that behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going a different way with this as I couldn't get it working properly even with it being rewritten by @alvits but it did certaintly help so I wanted to say thank you.

I ended up just gathering some stats from several servers to put a list of caching plugins together and came up with:

```
for wppath in $(find /home/*/ \( -path mail -o -path virtfs -o -path cache \) -prune -o -type f -name wp-config.php) ; do
        wppluginpath="${wppath//wp-config.php/}wp-content/plugins"
        if [ -d "$wppluginpath"/cache-enabler ] || [ -d "$wppluginpath"/comet-cache-pro ] || [ -d "$wppluginpath"/hyper-cache ] || [ -d "$wppluginpath"/quick-cache ] || [ -d "$wppluginpath"/zencache ] || [ -d "$wppluginpath"/comet-cache ] || [ -d "$wppluginpath"/wp-fastest-cache ] || [ -d "$wppluginpath"/w3-total-cache ] || [ -d "$wppluginpath"/wp-super-cache ] ; then
                echo "Found caching plugin in $wppluginpath" ; else
                echo "No caching plugin found in $wppluginpath"
                cd "$wppluginpath" || return
                wp --allow-root plugin install cache-enabler --activate --skip-plugins --skip-themes
                chown -R $(stat -c '%U' .): cache-enabler
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

The error `-bash: [: /home/userB/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/: binary operator expected` means that the pathname contains a whitespace.

First and foremost, don't parse the output of `ls`. Use glob instead.

Second, always quote variable names to avoid word splitting and unintentional globbing. This is the root cause of your issue.

Example:

```
[ -d /path/name space/to/something.conf ]
-bash: [: /path/name: binary operator expected
```

Your new script should look like:

```
for i in /var/cpanel/users/*; do 
        WPPATH=$(find "/home/${i##*/}/public_html/" -type f -name wp-config.php)
        WPPLUGINPATH="${WPPATH%/*}/wp-content/plugins/" # Useless use of echo
        if pushd "$WPPLUGINPATH"; then
                compgen -G "${WPPLUGINPATH}*cache*" > /dev/null || wp --allow-root plugin install cache-enabler --skip-plugins --skip-themes
                sleep 3
                chown -R "${i##*/}" "$WPPLUGINPATH"
                echo "$WPPLUGINPATH"
                popd
        fi
done
```

As [@Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) has mentioned in the comment below, this `find "/home/${i##*/}/public_html/" -type f -name wp-config.php` could yield multiple result. Use a for loop to work on each of them.

This line `[ -d "$WPPLUGINPATH"*cache* ]` will only work if it expands to a single pathname. Use bash builtin `compgen` instead. `compgen` will generate filename completion based on the pattern `"${WPPLUGINPATH}*cache*"`. It will return true if patterns can be generated or false when there's no file with the pattern.

Last but not least, change your habit of using all-caps variables to avoid inadvertently overwriting an environment variable.

Comment: Plenty of bugs still present here. Won't behave well if there's more than one file matching `wp-config.php` in its name -- should either iterate over results or take only the first one. The `*cache*` won't expand because it's in quotes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - the quotes bug was by me typing too quickly. The all-caps name is just too lazy for me to modify but should have mentioned like you did in this comment. I'll make a quick edit while i have time.

Comment: well -- it's a bit trickier than just taking out the quotes to fix it properly, because you need to handle the case when there's more than one match, which would cause `test` to fail. Checking for whether `"$WPPLUGINPATH"*cache*/` expands to a list of items where the first entry actually exists should suffice to be correct, though. (*If* the OP actually got that right as it was -- I wonder if they really meant `"$WPPLUGINPATH/"*cache*`).

Comment: `$WPPLUGINPATH*cache*` is correct since `$WPPLUGINPATH` would be someting like /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ the trailing slash would be included in the variable

Comment: @JCats - that's totally understood. What Charles and I were talking is that `"$WPPLUGINPATH"*cache*` could resolve in multiple paths which will make the test `[ -d "$WPPLUGINPATH"*cache* ]` expand to `[ -d  
/home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/app-cache  
/home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/tmp-cache ...]`. If this happens then you'll get `bash: [: too many arguments` or your original issue `binary operator expected`.

Comment: Ah I see, yeah I think that's the case as I am still having issues running what you wrote `binary operator expected` and `chown: invalid user: ‘/var/cpanel/users/userA’`

Comment: Also as far as `"$WPPLUGINPATH"*cache*` and being more specific on the path, I'm not sure that is possible as there are tons and tons of caching plugins which is why I'm using such a broad wildcard.  Is there anyway to just have it stop after it finds the first instance of cache to avoid the current issue?

Comment: @JCats - your concern is easily answered by `compgen`. See my edit.

Comment: @JCats - the reason you were getting `chown: invalid user: ‘/var/cpanel/users/userA’` is because I forgot to update that line in accordance with the new `for` loop. Updated it too. All `$i` should now be `${i##*/}`.